# Technologies Before Learning Ionic Framwork

Tags: ionic-framework

I am learning Android. I heard with Ionic Framework we can develop apps for multiple platform.

My question is, **what technologies should I learn before learning  Ionic Framework.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic framework have two versions Ionic v1 and Ioonic v2.

If you want learn Ionic v1

first you have to learn

1. [angularJs](https://angularjs.org/)

If you want learn Ionic v2

first you have to learn

1. [Angular2](https://angular.io/)

   both versions you have to learn

   HTML, Css, Sass , Cordova